# Accessing Dependency from Artifactory using Gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, artifactory

I have an artifact that has been published to my local Artifactory repository and now I am trying to pull that artifact into a project with gradle.

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Could not find com.company.app:myapplication:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/company/app/...pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/company/app/...jar

     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/company/app...pom
     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/company/app...jar
     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/company/app...pom
     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/company/app....jar
```

This error suggests that it's not even looking at the local artifactory repository. Below are my `build.gradle` files

---

### Project Level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url '${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-release-local'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### App Level `build.gradle`

```
allprojects{
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.company.app:myapplication:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was

1. The maven url needs to be outside of the buildscript
2. The maven url needs to be in the App level, not Project level `build.gradle`

Below are my current `build.gradle` files that work:

### Project Level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### App Level `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url '${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-release-local'
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.company.app:myapplication:1.0.0'
}
```

---

**NOTE:** I removed the jfrog plugin because it's only needed if you are publishing to Artifactory.

Comment: Can you please tell me why you are using jCenter in all repositories ...why not the path of artifactory. i also want to get google support package dependency resolved from artifactory .

Comment: I can't remember why I had to specify jcenter in allprojects, but I don't think jcenter is required to access local Artifactory repositories. I just included it because it's the standard repository to pull in other third-party dependencies.

Comment: i want my standard dependency to be also downloaded from Artifactory. Do you know how to do that

Comment: you have to first publish the dependency to Artifactory. This question only deals with pulling from Artifactory. You should probably just start a new question.